# Maximizing Polygon area out of a set of overlapping polygons in geopandas / shapely

Tags: python, pandas, geospatial, geopandas, geo

Dear Stackoverflow community,

I have multiple overlapping Polygons/MultiPoligons within an GeoDataFrame in geopandas, which look like this:

[Multiple polygons in GeoDataFrame](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oYB2U.png)

Now I want to calculate a polygon, which consists of 1, 2, 3, ..., n polygons of this set so that the resulting polygon has the maximum possible area.

Do you have any idea, how this could be done (efficiently)?

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: What is your definition of `maximum possible area`? A union of them?

Comment: @swatchai Yes, exactly. A union of n polygons to maximize the area covered.

Comment: When people see `efficiently`, they will think ... think. You won't get an answer very quick.